# How remove 1st ":" word from line in txt file?

Tags: regex, filereader, streamreader

Please see my textfile data below

```
roydwk27:teenaibuchytilibu5762sumonkhan:IJQRiq&76:8801627574057
deonnarsi15:latashajcclaypoolejcv5946sumonkhan:JKVWjv&20:8801627573929
ernaalo68:lindaohschletteoha1797sumonkhan:OPYZoy&84:8801628302709
dorathyshi56:fredrickaslperkinsonsle8932sumonkhan:STJKsj&30:8801621846709
londassg15:nataliaunmcredmondung5478sumonkhan:UVDEud&61:8801624792536
xiaoexu39:miriamfyboatwrightfyr3810sumonkhan:IJZAiz&47:8801626854856
```

I am want delete first word until `:`
like

```
roydwk27:
deonnarsi15:
ernaalo68:
dorathyshi56:
```

actually I am want if sumonkhan starting line then no problem but if sumonkhan line area 1st position available `:` with something then need remove this.

below actually data show in my .txt file

```
 nataliaunmcredmondung5478sumonkhan:UVDEud&61:8801624792536
 miriamfyboatwrightfyr3810sumonkhan:IJZAiz&47:8801626854856
```

all line available sumonkhan so if sumon khan starting position like this then good else delete this `:` full word not full line.

Comment: What programming language are you using? What have you tried so far?

Comment: a) Can you put your desired outputs ? b) What have you done so far?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232657/delete-till-first-occurrence-of-colon-using-sed

Comment: c# webbrowser programming

Comment: maybe `cut -f2- -d: file.txt`?

Comment: What is a `sumonkhan`?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this regex would help you. This regex deletes everything until first colon(:).
If you are reading a file then, read it line by line and run following regex on each line.

```
$str = 'roydwk27:teenaibuchytilibu5762sumonkhan:IJQRiq&76:8801627574057';
$str =~ s/^(?:.*?):(.*)/$1/g;
```

This code is in perl, you can re-write equivalent code in any other language.

Answer (score 0):

See this demo at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/oY3uG4/2).

`^[\w\d]+:(.*)`

```
^        // match the beginning of a line
[\w\d]+  // match any letter and any number
:        // match ":" literally
(        // start of the capturing group
  .*     // match any characters
)        // end of capturing group
```

Now in all your matches in the first group you have the text you want matched. Note the `g` (global) and `m` (multiline) modifiers.